# No response from running Tomcat: does not start, does nothing

Tags: apache, tomcat, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible

I'm using Ansible to spin up a new Amazon EC2 install, and then I install Java and Tomcat (via the yum module). After placing the war for sample project from the Apache website in the webapps directory, I go and run the the command (below), nothing happens. It returns with response, no error. I've checked both the IP and port 8080 and Tomcat is not running.

```
[centos@sonar-test webapps]$ sudo systemctl start tomcat
[centos@sonar-test webapps]$ sudo systemctl start tomcat
[centos@sonar-test webapps]$
```

For reference, I was following this tutorial as well:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-7-on-centos-7-via-yum

Comment: Have you checked the Tomcat logs, specifically `catalina.out`, to see if there are any error messages?

Comment: You check IP but do you have security rules to view 8080 - can you just run `curl localhost:8080` from the ec2 instance to check if you have something from tomcat or your ec2 settings

Comment: The only thing in the logs is "tomcat-7.0.54 RPM installed."


When I curl I get a large html document with various apache-esque things on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment on my question running `curl` in your ec2 instance

> When I curl I get a large html document with various apache-esque things on it

It means Tomcat is installed and running.

If you don't access it, its because of your [security group rules](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html#security-group-rules)

In your ec2 console, select the Security Groups option. Edit the rules that is associated with your ec2 instance (the one running Tomcat) and permits inbound connections to port 8080 (so you can make request to your Tomcat server) and port 80 if you're running Apache (or nginx/another web server). If you're not sure about security, you can restrict the inbound traffic to come only from your IP so you can test but no-one else can make request.